# Acumatica generic inquiry how to export more than one GI as xml

Tags: acumatica

I know you can export one GI at a time to xml, I'm wondering you can select all user GI and export to XML as a backup.

Thanks

Comment: What is your problem ? what you tried ? or can't you elaborate what you are asking  ? this type of posts will be closed soon as off topic

Comment: The question is clear when considering the Acumatica tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a customization project and include all the generic inquiries you need in one package. The project can be exported and imported which includes all of your attached GIs. We do this already and works great. Do not forget to update from database when making changes before re-exporting.

Simple list of steps if you have not created a project before: (using 5.30)

1. System > Customization > Customization Projects > create a new project (save)
2. Click on the hyper-link for your project name to open the customization project window.
3. Click on Generic Inquiries
4. Click the add (plus symbol) and check/select all of your GIs and click save. Note the 'RELOAD FROM DATABASE' option. Do this step when you make changes to your GI that you need to update into your package as this does not happen automatically when saving changes to your GIs.
5. You should see the list of Generic Inquiries include all that you selected
6. In the upper right under File (still in the Customization project window) select 'Export Project Package'. A zip file will be downloaded from the site which includes all of your XML for each GI

Comment: no problem. Don't forget to mark the question as answered to show completed.