# Acumatica - Export and Import all generic inquiries to another company

Tags: acumatica

Is there a quick way or any development to export all generic inquiries in one tenant to another.  I know you can individually export to xml and import back.
Thanks

Comment: How is this question different than your last question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908124/acumatica-generic-inquiry-how-to-export-more-than-one-gi-as-xml

Comment: Actually no difference, I've forgotten this question is already answered..oops

Comment: No worries. I think you can delete a post since this is a repeat question

Answer (score 1):

You can include all the neccessary GIs into customization project in System->Customization->Customization Projects